# ActionBarSherlock notification on tab

Tags: android, tabs, notifications, actionbarsherlock

Im use ActionBarSherlock.
Please, tell me the way, How may set Text notification on Tab, for example - total new messages, that so as in this image
[image]

OR In the simplest case, at least on the tab to display the image letterbox when new mail arrives:

[image]

I create Tab with PagerAdapter, And:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
```

...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    instance = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locations = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations);
    pager = ((ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager));               
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    for (String location: locations) {
        Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setText(location);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
    }
}
```

In this lib https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger need that a TABS call ONLY as `findViewById(R.id.target_view)`,
in my case it is - `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger. check this

Comment: @Raghunandan This http://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger not incompatible with ActionBarSherlock in particular with PagerAdapter

Comment: @what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Raghunandan Im edit question

Comment: I did it until with use CustomView and RelativeLayout